# iOS 13 can't playback audio after capture (recording) is stopped (Web Audio API)

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

It seems after a recent iOS update (13.1.3) a bug appeared with Safari and audio recording.

Because the MediaRecorder is not supported by Safari/iOS I use (some polyfill) `getUserMedia` for capturing and `ScriptProcessorNode` for recording. After recording is finished raw data is decoded to wav and then audio can be played. Until recently it worked.

Now I've discovered a strange behavior. The recording is finished successfully but I can't playback the result audio. Playback doesn't start and there is no any errors. It's seems like Safari can't play audio when device/context is busy with capturing or etc. If I minimize browser to tray and open after some time (~10 sec) playback is work well.

This problem can be reproduced here
https://ai.github.io/audio-recorder-polyfill/

but this work fine
https://kaliatech.github.io/web-audio-recording-tests/dist/#/test1
https://danielstorey.github.io/WebAudioTrack/index.html

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just update iOS from 13.1.3 to 13.2.3 and now all works fine